# How to map C-a a to go to the beginning of a line in a nested tmux session using prefix C-a?

Tags: tmux

Right now I use the following settings (in my local ~/.tmux.conf file) which allow me to use C-Space as my prefix key in my local tmux sessions and C-a as my prefix in my nested tmux sessions (i.e. through ssh):

Local .tmux.conf

```
unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix C-Space
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix
```

Remote .tmux.conf

```
set -g prefix C-Space
```

How can I map C-a+a in my nested session to go to the beginning of the line?

Comment: So by pressing just `C-a+a` you want that your internal's session cursor moved to beginning of line?

Comment: Yes, or C-a+C-a if possible...

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do

```
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix
# this binding sends prefix to internal tmux session.
# So when you press it, it invokes prefix mode on internal tmux
```

And everything should work fine.

Or if you really need to have `C-a` sending prefix

In remote .tmux.conf

```
# for C-a+a
bind-key a send-keys C-a
# for C-a+C-a
bind-key C-a send-keys C-a
```